# Comparing dates with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following test:

```
it 'gives the correct last parsed result' do
 expect(FactoryGirl.create(:category_page_with_parsed_results).last_parsed_result.date).to eql(Date.parse('2012-01-01'))
end
```

And it fails like this:

```
 expected: Sun, 01 Jan 2012
 got: Sun, 01 Jan 2012 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

The thing here is that when I create that Factory, I don't write any 00:00:00 time at all, so I don't know why is it returning it that way.

Any thoughts on how should I test this?

Comment: does `last_parsed_result` is in `timestamp`, to be specific what is its class ?

Comment: Its class is: ``ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone``

Comment: created a new answer, didn't tested it. give a try. May be that will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, do this

```
expect(FactoryGirl.create(:category_page_with_parsed_results).last_parsed_result.to_date).to eql(Date.parse('2012-01-01'))
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'm guessing your "last_parsed_result" object has a date property that is stored in the database.  Playing around in irb (Ruby 2.1.0) console I have:

```
require 'date'
Date.parse('2012-01-01').to_s  => "2012-01-01"
DateTime.parse('2012-01-01').to_s => "2012-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"
```

My guess is that last_parsed_result.date is a DateTime object and so that's why you're getting the 00:00:00 time.

Comment: Mmmm but how do I test they are equal?